# powershell script stopes working after compiled to exe

Tags: powershell, exe

i have a simpler script that makes some zip files from a folder with some changes for each folder depending how many .html files is in the asset folder.

everything works perfect.

except when i compile it to a exe.  Tried ps2exe and powershell pro tools

2 text fields that need data
2 buttons

- first button when presed checks if ther is data in the textboxes . if true it runs the script ..
- second button only opens a folder on the pc.

when exe is compiled and i run the file.

the GUI Loads but nothing happens when i puch the buttons. no error no nothing

see the code here

https://codeshare.io/6pXE3z

Comment: Note that the executable unpacks your PowerShell script in a different temporary folder... What happend when you enter the fullpath in your `TextBox1`?

Comment: You wrote C# code in PowerShell to compile it into an exe. Why not just write C# code in the first place and compile it with the regular tools used for that and have the added benefit of proper debugging?

Comment: Define your functions **before** (= above) you use them and also move `$form.Topmost = $true` to your `---[Form]---` code block.